# Where is the best place to store globals (auth token) in Android

Tags: android, authentication, access-token

I'm pretty new to android. I want to know where the best place is to store something like a auth token that I get from logging in on my server. With every subsequent request, I will have to post this auth token. Sure I could keep a global class somewhere, but I just want to know what a good / standard way is to store data that persists across `activities` and `intents`. Thanks!

Comment: Dropbox and Box sdk example apps use `SharedPreferences` to store auth token. Seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

`SharedPreferences` is the way to go.
See doc here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Some example code is like below.

To save the token:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(some_key, your_auth_token_string);
editor.commit();
```

To get the token:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String auth_token_string = settings.getString(some_key, ""/*default value*/);
```

Comment: You might want to encrypt it before saving to sharedprefs